# CloudFront is ignoring custom Origin provided by Lambda@Edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to configure **CloudFront** so it fetches the content from **S3** or from an **external origin** depending on the value of a **header**.

To do that, I have implemented a **Lambda@Edge** which is triggered on **Origin Request** event. It **changes the origin to a custom one** but, somehow, CloudFront is **still accessing to S3** content.

This is the Lambda function:

```
'use strict';

const PRERENDER_HOST = 'xxxxx.ngrok.io'
const IS_SSL = false

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('event', JSON.stringify(event))
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    const should_prerender = headers['x-should-prerender'] 
            ? JSON.parse(headers['x-should-prerender'][0].value)
            : false

    console.log('should prerender', should_prerender, 'existed', !!headers['x-should-prerender'])
    console.log('uri is', request.uri)
    if (should_prerender) {
        set_header('host', PRERENDER_HOST, headers)
        request.origin = {
            custom: {
                domainName: PRERENDER_HOST,
                port: IS_SSL ? 443 : 80,
                protocol: IS_SSL ? 'https' : 'http',
                readTimeout: 20,
                keepaliveTimeout: 5,
                customHeaders: {},
                path: request.uri,
                sslProtocols: ['TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1'],
            }
        }
    }

    console.log('request', JSON.stringify(request))

    callback(null, request)

    function set_header(name, value, store) {
        store[name.toLowerCase()] = [
            {
                key: name,
                value
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Next, I am pasting the content of the `request` that is being passed to the `callback`. This has been extracted from the related CloudWatch log. The log shows how the origin is established to the custom one.

```
{
   "uri" : "/index.html",
   "origin" : {
      "custom" : {
         "sslProtocols" : [
            "TLSv1",
            "TLSv1.1"
         ],
         "keepaliveTimeout" : 5,
         "port" : 80,
         "domainName" : "xxxxx.ngrok.io",
         "path" : "/index.html",
         "customHeaders" : {},
         "readTimeout" : 20,
         "protocol" : "http"
      }
   },
   "headers" : {
      "x-should-prerender" : [
         {
            "key" : "x-should-prerender",
            "value" : "true"
         }
      ],
      "host" : [
         {
            "key" : "host",
            "value" : "xxxxx.ngrok.io"
         }
      ],
      "upgrade-insecure-requests" : [
         {
            "value" : "1",
            "key" : "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"
         }
      ],
      "dnt" : [
         {
            "key" : "DNT",
            "value" : "1"
         }
      ],
      "x-forwarded-for" : [
         {
            "key" : "X-Forwarded-For",
            "value" : "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
         }
      ],
      "via" : [
         {
            "value" : "1.1 25xxxxxbcxxxx07847a7xxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
            "key" : "Via"
         }
      ],
      "user-agent" : [
         {
            "key" : "User-Agent",
            "value" : "Amazon CloudFront"
         }
      ],
      "accept-encoding" : [
         {
            "key" : "Accept-Encoding",
            "value" : "gzip"
         }
      ]
   },
   "clientIp" : "xxx.xx.xx.xxx",
   "querystring" : "",
   "method" : "GET"
}
```

Any idea of what could be happening here?

**UPDATE 1**: After trying with `https` everything worked. Still, no clue why it is not working with `http`.
**UPDATE 2**: Correcting a mistake. I wrote View Request instead of Origin Request. Thanks Michael for noticing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viewer Request triggers run in the "front side" of CloudFront -- the viewer side -- which is before the cache check.

The origin is "known" at that point, because the Cache Behavior matching has already occurred, but you can't influence origin selection on the viewer side, because CloudFront hasn't technically decided whether to even contact the origin, yet.

Changes to the origin server can only be made on the origin side (the back side, after the cache check) of CloudFront, in an Origin Request trigger.  It wouldn't make sense for a Viewer Request trigger to change the origin, because the origin is not part of the cache key, so if a Viewer Request trigger changed the origin, the cache would be then checked without any accommodation being made for the changed origin, so cached responses would not be assured to have even come from the right place.

You will need to use an Origin Request trigger, and you will need to whitelist `x-should-prerender` for forwarding to the origin (in the Cache Behavior settings) so that the trigger can see it.  If you don't want the origin to actually see it, you'll need to then use the trigger code to remove it, but it must be whitelisted in order for the Origin Request trigger to see it.

> If you want the function to change the request in a way that affects the response from the origin, use the origin request event.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-how-to-choose-event.html

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write Origin Request but wrote View by mistake. Upvoting you for noticing and providing such useful information.